# Reduce run time for DTW distance function

Tags: r, distance

I want to compute [DTW](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_time_warping) distance between columns of a data matrix. But current implementation takes terribly long time. Is there any other implementation of `dtw` which takes less time?

Here is the dummy data:

```
df <- data.frame(d1= rnorm(1500,10,5),d2= rnorm(1500,130,10),d3= rnorm(1500,200,10),d4= rnorm(1500,120,15),d5= rnorm(1500,700,25),d6= rnorm(1500,6,2),d7= rnorm(1500,760,15),d8= rnorm(1500,3000,08),d9= rnorm(1500,490,15),d10= rnorm(1500,321,21))
```

This function returns distance matrix using `DTWDistance()` function:

```
compute_dtw_distance_matrix  <- function(data_mat){
  library(TSdist) # for DTWDistance function
  cols = dim(data_mat)[2] # no. of columns or features
  dis_mat = matrix(0,nrow=cols,ncol=cols) # create result matrix
  # Here, I will compute only lower triangular matrix, later I will copy values to full matrix.
  # compute only lower traingular matrix
  for(row in 1:cols){
    ref_col = data_mat[,row]
    for(col in 1:row){
      comp_col = data_mat[,col]
      dis_mat[row,col] = DTWDistance(ref_col, comp_col)
    }
  }
  # convert lower_triangular to full_symmetric matrix
  for(i in 1:NROW(dis_mat)){
    for(j in 1:NCOL(dis_mat)){
      dis_mat[i,j] = dis_mat[j,i] 
    }
  }
  colnames(dis_mat) <- colnames(data_mat)
  row.names(dis_mat) <- colnames(data_mat)
  return(dis_mat)
}
```

Here are the running time statistic of this function on my machine:

```
 system.time(compute_dtw_distance_matrix(df))
       user  system elapsed 
     21.500   3.049  24.723
```

Is it possible to reduce the running time of this function?

Comment: `for(i in 1:NROW(dis_mat)){
    for(j in 1:NCOL(dis_mat)){ ... }}` is running over the full matrix - not only over the lower triangular. There are also other parts to optimize.

Comment: I believe the main issue is with `DTWDistance()` function. Any other implementation of the same should decrease overall time.

Comment: The algorithm is inherently O(nm) where n and m are the length of each times series. This is inherently much larger (roughly speaking, an order of magnitude) than calculating the Euclidean distance. If this is not a school requirement, you might take a look at the DTW package, which not only computes this distance, but also allows for graphing the final mapping (which looks pretty cool).

Comment: I didn't find DTWDistance function in the library TSclust or any of its dependencies. Maybe it's the version reason? And I agree with Haroon Rashid that the main issue is with your DTWDistance function, unless you find it and implement it more efficiently, you won't improve the performance.

Comment: @Consistency. I am sorry. It is TSdist library.

Comment: I read into the source code, and found that the function is already a wrapper around some C implementation of DTW distance calculation. Although somebody may rewrite the wrapper to make it a little more efficient, but I guess the main bottleneck is in the C function.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the `parallelDist` package which supports the parallel calculation of multi-dimensional Dynamic Time Warping distances.

The `parDist` function currently takes a list of matrices as an input argument for processing multi-dimensional data sets.

```
matrices.list <- lapply(as.list(df), function(x) t(as.matrix(x)))
```

`parDist` produces the same output in ~ **0.5s** with 8 threads compared to **18.44s** with the `compute_dtw_distance_matrix` function, using the following arguments:

```
res1 <- compute_dtw_distance_matrix(df)
res2 <- parDist(matrices.list, method = "dtw", step.pattern="symmetric2", window.type="none", upper = T, diag = T, threads = 8)
all.equal(as.matrix(res1), as.matrix(res2))
```

Here is a microbenchmark which includes different number of threads.

```
    expr        min         lq
                                                                                                  compute_dtw_distance_matrix(df) 17.9424328 18.1571842
 parDist(matrices.list, method = "dtw", step.pattern = "symmetric2",      window.type = "none", upper = T, diag = T, threads = 8)  0.5280135  0.5434037
 parDist(matrices.list, method = "dtw", step.pattern = "symmetric2",      window.type = "none", upper = T, diag = T, threads = 4)  0.6869948  0.6999783
 parDist(matrices.list, method = "dtw", step.pattern = "symmetric2",      window.type = "none", upper = T, diag = T, threads = 2)  1.0311007  1.0646326
 parDist(matrices.list, method = "dtw", step.pattern = "symmetric2",      window.type = "none", upper = T, diag = T, threads = 1)  1.6967269  1.7057925
       mean     median         uq        max neval
 18.4489183 18.4901471 18.6747947 18.9852819    10
  0.5547146  0.5568046  0.5657859  0.5727592    10
  0.7266116  0.7276621  0.7446920  0.7597008    10
  1.0796176  1.0742217  1.0812031  1.1792582    10
  1.7358018  1.7148310  1.7695766  1.8238875    10
```

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old question but I was looking for ways to speed up the distance matrix computation in R. I came across `RcppParallel` package which can be used with several distance functions for computing the distances. 
Details can be found at https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dtwclust/vignettes/parallelization-considerations.html